# Small rectangle appears with bootstrap popover

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip, popover

I have a popover on an image hover.
but when it appears, a small rectangle (circled in screenshot) is appearing.
I assume it's some kind of button... how to I make it disappear?

here's the code:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="">
   <img src="images/location1.png" width="100" height="100" alt="info-tooltip image" class="contactImgs" />
</a>  

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    //trigger: 'focus',
    trigger: 'hover',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return 'jbb" />';
    },
    title: 'Toolbox'
});
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YI1D.png)

Comment: are you using this `<a>` inside a `<ul><li>... </li></ul>` ? can you share code which reproduces this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.tooltip.top:before, .tooltip:before{

 display:none !important;   

 }
```

This is simply solved my problem !

In my case, I was using both bootstrap 4 and Foundation 6. So I have overridden the css.